# I cloned a github repo and trying to push it to Codecommit but I'm getting a 403 error

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, migration, aws-codecommit

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to take advantage of Codecommit.
After following this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository-existing.html) step by step, I'm stuck on the part where I successfully mirrored the repo I want to migrate to CodeCommit but when I try to push it using the following code:

```
git push https://git-codecommit.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/dev-test-repo --all
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/dev-test-repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
dkirali@Doruks-MacBook-Air aws-code-commit-demo %
```

as I've been searching for an answer all over the web, I can't seem to find the right one that helps me with my problem.

I have setup my .gitconfig to use AWS CLI for credential manager:

```
[credential]
        helper = !aws --profile builder codecommit credential-helper $@
        UseHttpPath = true
```

and also tried to find Codecommit passwords in the keychain but the file does not exist.
Any suggestions on what can I do to fix the problem?